# Why am I getting only newly added values in a list?

Tags: python

I have a code that looks like this:

```
if len_after > len_before:
    # get resource demand of finish_act
    r_finish_act = [d for a, d in zip(j_set, R) if a in finish_act]

    # update available resources
    for i in r_finish_act:
        x = i[0]
    avail_res[0] = avail_res[0] + x

else:
    avail_res[0] = avail_res[0]
```

The objective of this code is to get the resource demand of the finish activity/ies (`r_finish_act`) and add them to `avail_res[0]`. The first thing to check is if an activity is added in `finish_act`. This is done using the `if-statement`. Afterwards, `r_finish_act` is obtained using `j_set and R`.

```
j_set = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
R = [[0, 0], [4, 3], [2, 0], [2, 1], [0, 3], [1, 1], [1, 2], [2, 1], [0, 3], [2, 2], [0, 0]]
```

For example:

```
finish_act_before = [1]
avail_res[0] = 1
finish_act_after = [1, 2, 3] 
r_finish_act = [[4, 3], [2, 0]]
```

Output of the code above:

```
avail_res[0] = 1 + 2 = 3
```

Expected output:

```
avail_res[0] = 1 + 4 + 2 = 7
```

How could I make this change for the code above such that all `r_finish_act` of activities added in `finish_act` will be added to `avail_res[0]` and not just the last one? Note that activities to be finished vary. It can be just one activity, two, and so on.

Any help/suggestions would be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: The line ```avail_res[0] = avail_res[0] + x``` only adds the last choice of ```x``` from the ```for```-loop, so possibly you want that line to be part of the ```for```-body. However, from this snippet, it's not really possible to deduce what you want to do, e.g. what are ```len_after, len_before, finish_act, avail_res```?

Comment: You are looping over `r_finish_act` and only storing the last value: `x = i[0]`. When you loop over that, you should do `avail_res[0] += i[0]`

Comment: Add  list to tag

Comment: Try storing added finish activity/ies to a different variable. Afterwards, get its resource demand and add with avail_res[0].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed in the comments, either :

- you are basically missing an indentation in your `avail_res[0] = avail_res[0] + x` line
- you are missing a `+` here : `x = i[0]`. It should be `x += i[0]`

Note : don't do both :)